# Можно ли замапить две коллекции без потери данных?

Tags: .net, automapper

У меня есть две коллекции. Первая содержит в себе `Id` и `Name`. Вторая содержит в себе `Id` (идентичный `Id` из первой коллекции), поле `Name=null` (вот его нам и нужно получить из первой коллекции), а также кучу других данных которые потерять нельзя.

Можно ли как-нибудь поле `Name` из первой коллекции занести в поле `Name` второй коллекции, не потеряв при этом все данных второй коллекции?

Comment: Как вам [такой](https://pastebin.com/rhUgChiE) вариант?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ как насчет тэга [tag:automapper]? :)

Comment: @andreycha и то верно...